# Determine potential function given initial conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields, potential

Assuming a radially symmetric circular disk (let's say r=1).

Given two simple initial conditions:

1. Potential at the centre is 4 V
2. Potential at the edges is 0 V

How would I determine the potential function?  My aim in the end is to take the gradient of this function to compute the electric field.

edit:  I have already tried to solve the Laplace equation, and the solution does not stand.  Also, the Kronecker delta function seems to be a correct solution, however it does not show the distribution and does not make sense as it means there is no other distribution surrounding.

note:  in background context, this is a set up for producing an alternating electric field. in a sense, we would consider the set up between the centre and outsides as capacitor plates.

Comment: Assuming you are looking at a 2D system, you need to solve Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 V = 0$ with your boundary conditions. Your problem has plane symmetry that can be used to simplify $\nabla^2$. Have a look at Stanley J Farlow, "PDE's for Scientists and Engineers", Dover. Chapter 34 deals with the case of an annulus of radii $R_1, R_2$, you have to look at the case $R_1 = 0, R_2 = 1$

Comment: Unfortunately I have solved the system with Laplace, however the solutions do not satisfy all conditions.  However, using the annulus may work.  I will keep you posted thank you!

Comment: With Laplace's equation there is a uniqueness theorem that states (see Griffiths, Introduction to Electrodynamics") *The solution to Laplace's equation in some volume V is uniquely determined if V is uniquely determined if V is specified on the boundary surface S*. It may be that your boundary condition V(r=1) = 1 V is not consistent with V(r=0) = 4 V. It might be that if you migrate this to the mathematics site you will get an answer.